# Issue with SASL mechanism in Kafka

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka

Use case -

Push data to Confluent cloud kafka from spring boot

Error -

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find a 'KafkaClient' entry in the JAAS configuration. System property 'java.security.auth.login.config' is not set
```

I have gone through multiple discussions in SO and seems like I am not missing anything , below is my kafka config , I am still not sure why it's unable to create the client

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.CommonClientConfigs;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.common.config.SaslConfigs;
//import org.apache.kafka.common.config.SaslConfigs;
import org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.ProducerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@Configuration
public class KakfaConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, User> producerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();

        config.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "pkc-l7pr2.ap-south-1.aws.confluent.cloud:9092");
       
        config.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        config.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);
        
      

        config.put(CommonClientConfigs.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG, "SASL_SSL");
        config.put(SaslConfigs.SASL_MECHANISM, "PLAIN");

        config.put("sasl.jaas.config", "org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule   required username='test'   password='tes1/FRi/BNfpRhWwLlxb573NdgpQZ6SCTZ';");

        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(config);
    }


    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, User> kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
    }


}
```

I am providing jaas config in the properties so not sure why it's unable to pick up the value. Any help is highly appreciated

Seems like Jaas values are not being passed , not sure what's the reason -

```
acks = 1
    batch.size = 16384
    block.on.buffer.full = false
    bootstrap.servers = [pkc-l7pr2.ap-south-1.aws.confluent.cloud:9092]
    buffer.memory = 33554432
    client.id = 
    compression.type = none
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    interceptor.classes = null
    key.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
    linger.ms = 0
    max.block.ms = 60000
    max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 5
    max.request.size = 1048576
    metadata.fetch.timeout.ms = 60000
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    partitioner.class = class org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner
    receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    retries = 0
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.mechanism = PLAIN
    security.protocol = SASL_PLAINTEXT
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = null
    ssl.key.password = null
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.protocol = TLS
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    timeout.ms = 30000
    value.serializer = class org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
```

I am now able to resolve the issue after upgrading kafka client library to latest however in another program instead of adding the properties in config ,I am keeping in application.properties file and it's failing

Application.properties

```
spring.kafka.properties.sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
spring.kafka.properties.bootstrap.servers=pkc-l7pr2.ap-south-1.aws.confluent.cloud:9092
spring.kafka.properties.sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule   required username='test'   password='test/FRi/BNfpRhWwLlxb573NdgpQZ6SCTZ';
spring.kafka.properties.security.protocol=SASL_SSL


# Best practice for higher availability in Apache Kafka clients prior to 3.0
spring.kafka.properties.session.timeout.ms=45000

spring.kafka.producer.key-serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.IntegerSerializer
spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
server.port=9099
```

Error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at io.pranav.kafkatest.Producer.lambda$1(KafkaTestApplication.java:61) ~[classes/:na]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:106) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxZip$ZipCoordinator.drain(FluxZip.java:756) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxZip$ZipInner.onNext(FluxZip.java:915) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxInterval$IntervalRunnable.run(FluxInterval.java:125) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
    at reactor.core.scheduler.PeriodicWorkerTask.call(PeriodicWorkerTask.java:59) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
    at reactor.core.scheduler.PeriodicWorkerTask.run(PeriodicWorkerTask.java:73) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_291]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308) ~[na:1.8.0_291]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) ~[na:1.8.0_291]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294) ~[na:1.8.0_291]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[na:1.8.0_291]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[na:1.8.0_291]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_291]
    Suppressed: java.lang.Exception: #block terminated with an error
        at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:99) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.blockFirst(Flux.java:2600) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
        at io.pranav.kafkatest.Producer.generate(KafkaTestApplication.java:61) ~[classes/:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_291]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_291]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_291]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_291]
        at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.doInvoke(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:344) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.processEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:229) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.onApplicationEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:166) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:421) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:378) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.started(EventPublishingRunListener.java:108) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$started$5(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:78) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1259) ~[na:1.8.0_291]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:120) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:114) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.started(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:78) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:309) [spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1312) [spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) [spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at io.pranav.kafkatest.KafkaTestApplication.main(KafkaTestApplication.java:25) [classes/:na]
```

Producer

```
class Producer{
    
    private KafkaTemplate<Integer, String> template;
    Faker faker;
     
    @EventListener(ApplicationStartedEvent.class)
    public void generate() {
        faker = Faker.instance();
        System.out.println(faker.hobbit().quote());

        final Flux<Long> interval = Flux.interval(Duration.ofMillis(1_000));
        System.out.println(interval);
        System.out.println("Next Interval ..."+faker.random().nextInt(42)); 
        
        final Flux<String> quotes =  Flux.fromStream(Stream.generate(() ->  faker.hobbit().quote()));
        System.out.println("Quote is .." + quotes.toString());
        Flux.zip(interval, quotes).map(it -> template.send("hobbit", 11, "hi") ).blockFirst();
        System.out.println("Data pushed..");

    }
```

Comment: Which version of kafka-client library are you using?

Comment: I am able to resolve this after updating  kafka-client  library to latest which has sasl.jaas.config in saslconfig class...

Answer (score 0):

`sasl.jaas.conf` was introduced in kafka-client 0.10.2. Can you check you have a recent kafka-clients release. The `SASL_JAAS_CONFIG` constant is located in the `org.apache.kafka.common.config.SaslConfigs` class